# Override a package class in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create multiple apps based on my own package in flutter / dart. Some apps should override some classes inside this package to use their own custom implementation. I have already created some abstract classes and created some classes that use this abstract classes. The problem is now that i haven't found any solution to use the overwritten classes instead of the normal classes.

I already tried to create a configuration class and set the new types here but i cannot create an instance based on the `Type` Datatype.